# What is the prototype for Boost::signals2::signal::connect

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals, boost-signals2

I would like to encapsulate a signals2::signal object ans expose the connect and operator() functions, but how does their prototypes look like?

Example:

```
#include <boost/signals2/signal.hpp>

template<typename T> class A {
    public:
        typedef boost::signals2::signal<T> SIG_T;

        void connect( TYPE1 arg ){
            s.connect(arg);
        }

        void fire ( TYPE2 arg ){
            s(arg);
        }

    private:
        SIG_T s;
};
```

So how to express the correct type for TYPE1 and TYPE2, I assume it is something like SIG_T::???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`connect` takes `typename SIG_T::slot_type const &`.

`operator()` takes `typename SIG_T::argument_type` (also defined as `typename SIG_T::arg<0>::type`).

Alternatively, you could use templates to avoid worrying about the exact definition and accept anything convertible to the correct types:

```
template <typename Slot> void connect(Slot const & slot) {s.connect(slot);}
template <typename Arg> void fire(Arg const & arg) {s(arg);}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `signal` class synopsis is [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/signals2/signal.html), including the signatures of the `signal::connect` overloads.